# Reopening appcelerator app crashes

Tags: javascript, android, tabs, appcelerator

I'm building a small app in Appcelerator and in my index.js I've created 3 tabs and opened them in a Tabgroup, pretty basic stuff.

See my code below:

```
var win1 = Alloy.createController('getContacts').getView();
var win2 = Alloy.createController('getGroups').getView();
var win3 = Alloy.createController('settings').getView();

var tab1 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    window: win1,
    icon:'KS_all.png',
    backgroundSelectedColor:'#ffffff'
}),
tab2 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    window: win2,
    icon:'KS_groups.png',
    backgroundSelectedColor:'#ffffff'
}),
tab3 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    window: win3,
    icon:'KS_settings.png',
    backgroundSelectedColor:'#ffffff'
}),
tabGroup = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({
    tabs: [tab1, tab2, tab3],
    tabsBackgroundColor:'#ff6600',
    tabsBackgroundSelectedColor:'#ffffff',
    exitOnClose:'true'
});

tabGroup.open();
```

Everything seems to be working fine when installing the app on my phone, switching between tabs/windows are working as they should and events/functions within my windows firing properly.

The problem start when I close the app, when one of my tab windows is openend and I press the android back button. The app shuts down but when I reopen the app it results in an alert message popping up saying the app has stopped working.

I can't seem to find whats wrong with my code, could it be that it's phone (HTC M8) or Appcelerator related?

**EDIT**

I've tested the suggested methods by Soumya and Fokke, which resulted in my app not crashing. It also closes and continues as it should on restart. I've changed  declaring win1, win2 and win3 from using the createController to createWindow like so:

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'red', title:'Contacts'});
var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'green', title:'Groups'});
var win3 = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'blue', title:'Settings'});
```

And changed the exitOnClose in my createTabGroup from a string to a boolean (I'm deeply sorry Fokke). This seems to work perfectly. Great, now I can continue building my app. But how am I able to use the code (parsing json data) from my js files I wanted to use as windows?

Copying the code from my files (getContacts.js, getGroups.js and settings.js) into the index.js shouldn't be the solution, right?

Comment: Can't see any problems here. Could be something wrong with your `getContacts`, `getGroups`, or `settings` controllers. Try to create three simple windows instead and test.

Comment: May I suggest to steps to debug this? 1) Try `Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'red'})` with `red`, `green`, `blue`, for all three Windows to rule out the Windows you use. 2) Remove `exitOnClose:true` (which should be a bool, not a string by the way) to see if that's a factor. If so, report as bug.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation link, there is a sample code. Can you try to run the code and see if that works out for you.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-method-close

The next step is to createWindow and assign it to win1, win2 and win3, instead of doing createController.

Can you confirm the above two scenarios work fine.

Comment: The tabgroup is created on app launch, and I use these windows for loading and placing external data (from my online database). Isn't this process too large (creating all the windows, loading and configuring all the data) when the starts?